# Uninstall or Repair Nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I had Nodejs and npm and try to remove them with windows uninstaller.
The uninstall failed so I deleted the file, try to remove it with the registry editor and delete it also from the PATH in the system environments.
Now I'm trying to install them back, and get this error every time:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZIdI.png)

Any help, please?

Comment: To remove an app completely, I use ```RevoUninstaller_Portable```

Comment: Hey, its indeed remove all the files of Node,js thnx.
Yet the error still happens.